# Generate featured images old posts

Tags: functions, scripts

I am looking for a way to generate featured image per post based on the first image in the post for old posts without a set featured image. I'm switching from handmade thumbnails to auto generated featured images. With new posts I got this working, but I don't want to set a featured image of my other 2000 posts by hand. Found some plugins, but they aren't working well or not supported and the info I did find here is all about setting the image with new posts. Any hook, script or function for this? Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into this post: http://ken.ph/first-image-of-wordpress-post-as-thumbnail/

Or if you're comfortable with MySql try using this (obviously check it on local database first):

```
INSERT into wp_postmeta (meta_value, meta_key, post_id) 
SELECT DISTINCT(ID), post_type , post_parent 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type= 'attachment' 
AND post_parent !=0 
AND post_status='inherit';
UPDATE wp_postmeta set meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' 
WHERE meta_key='attachment'
```